# How do i reload NLog type instances without shutting down the appdomain?

Tags: nlog, xunit, createinstance

NLog provides a factory for specifying how to create different instances of classes used when setting up NLog, for example targets and renderers.

```
ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.CreateInstance
```

I have a bunch of unit tests (XUnit) that rely on being able to configure this function for testing different behaviours with my custom logging functionality. However, this function is only run once, when requesting the first logger after starting the appdomain. This causes problems with all other tests running in the same appdomain since the NLog framework will not execute `CreteInstance` again until the appdomain is restarted, which it won't be when running the Visual Studio XUnit runner for example.

How can I force NLog to recreate the different types specified with `CreteInstance`?

Comment: Is my answer working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Set the default to `null` and next time a new default will be created.

```
ConfigurationItemFactory.Default = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response. However, I do not want to reset to default, I want to be able to change the configuration inbetween tests.

By setting `ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.CreateInstance` and then executing `LogManager.Configuration = LogManager.Configuration.Reload();` and resetting the factory after the test has executed (by setting the default factory to `null`, as you said), or by setting `CreteInstance` back to what it was before did the trick.

I must say I don't like the implementation. It's confusing how to reset NLog. You would think `LogManager.Shutdown();` would do the trick, but no. 
Also, I thought the point of `ConfigurationItemFactory` was to provide custom dependency resolving. But since it is only run once for each type, it totally neglects any scoping. It should be the implmentation of `CreteInstance` that decides what to do when something needs resolving, by using an IOC container for example.